# Pandas, multiple calculation per row of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, rows

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['31/12/2015','31/12/2016','31/12/2017','31/12/2018',
                            '31/12/2019','31/12/2020','31/12/2015','31/12/2016',
                            '31/12/2017','31/12/2018','31/12/2019','31/12/2020'], 
                   'season': ['S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2'], 
                   'total' : [1,0,0,0,0.022313421,0.053791041,0,0,0.307783314,0,0,0] })
df.date=  pd.to_datetime(df.date)
print(df)  

         date season         total
0  2015-12-31     S1      1.000000
1  2016-12-31     S1      0.000000
2  2017-12-31     S1      0.000000
3  2018-12-31     S1      0.000000
4  2019-12-31     S1      0.022313
5  2020-12-31     S1      0.053791
6  2015-12-31     S2      0.000000
7  2016-12-31     S2      0.000000
8  2017-12-31     S2      0.307783
9  2018-12-31     S2      0.000000
10 2019-12-31     S2      0.000000
11 2020-12-31     S2      0.000000
```

I would like to do several calculations for each row based on the value contained in the column 'total' to obtain a dataframe in the following format (example for the first row):

```
         date season         total   calculation id       result
0  2015-12-31     S1      1.000000                1           x1
0  2015-12-31     S1      1.000000                2           x2
0  2015-12-31     S1      1.000000                3           x3  
0  2015-12-31     S1      1.000000                4           x4
0  2015-12-31     S1      1.000000                5           x5
```

basically something like:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for i, a in enumerate(np.linspace(0,getattr(row,'total'),6)):
          assing the result of the calculation to the column result
```

Any idea on how i could do that? For the sake of the example, the result column could be evaluated to  `a*5` in the loop.

Thanks for your help,

Pierre

Comment: For clarification - basically do you need replication of rows?

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean by replication of rows. But in the end I would have the rows duplicated depending on the lenght of the parameter in the linspace function. But the value in the column result is going to be different for each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do the job and "duplicating" the row, is first create a column list_results for each row in df:

```
df['list_result'] = df['total'].apply(lambda a: np.linspace(0,a,6)*5)
```

From this column, you can use `stack` to create a serie with a row for each value in the lists, and by setting index first, you can work directly on a serie:

```
df_output = (df.set_index(['date', 'season','total'])['list_result'] 
               # set index and work on the column list_result
                 .apply(pd.Series).stack() #will expand the lists of results as rows
                 .reset_index()) # to get back the column 'date', 'season','total'
#you can rename the column
df_output.columns = ['date', 'season','total', 'calculation_id', 'result']
```

And the first line of df_output are:

```
         date season     total  calculation_id    result
0  2015-12-31     S1  1.000000               0  0.000000
1  2015-12-31     S1  1.000000               1  1.000000
2  2015-12-31     S1  1.000000               2  2.000000
3  2015-12-31     S1  1.000000               3  3.000000
4  2015-12-31     S1  1.000000               4  4.000000
5  2015-12-31     S1  1.000000               5  5.000000
```

Note that it's not stricly the result you expect, but by using `np.linspace(0,getattr(row,'total'),6)` it's what you will get, then you can change this function when creating the list_result.

Comment: That's awesome and much better than my dirty loop appending and concatenating dataframes! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['31/12/2015','31/12/2016','31/12/2017','31/12/2018','31/12/2019','31/12/2020', '31/12/2015','31/12/2016','31/12/2017','31/12/2018','31/12/2019','31/12/2020'], 'season':['S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2'], 'total' : [1,0,0,0,0.022313421,0.053791041,0,0,0.307783314,0,0,0]  })

df.date=  pd.to_datetime(df.date)

df['key'] = 1 #add key for merge

ids = pd.DataFrame({'calculation_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'key': 1})

df = pd.merge(df, ids, on = 'key').drop('key', 1) #cartesian product

df['result'] = df['total']*df['calculation_id']

print(df)
```

The idea is to create another dataframe containing your calculation ids. Then "cross join" the dataframe with your original. Finally, multiply total by the calculation id to find the result.